# Unsure how to configure credentials for AWS Amplify cli user - ready to ditch Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I have a react Amplify App. All I want to do is work on it, push the changes to amplify, etc. These are all standard and basic commands like amplify push.

The problem is that shortly after starting to work on my app ( a month or two ), I was no longer allowed to push, pull, or work on the app from the command line. There is no explanation, and the only error is this ...

```
An error occurred during the push operation: /
Access Denied

✅ Report saved: /var/folders/8j/db7_b0d90tq8hgpfcxrdlr400000gq/T/storygraf/report-1658279884644.zip

✔ Done
```

The logs created from the error show this.

error.json

```
{
"message": "Access Denied",
"code": "AccessDenied",
"region": null,
"time": "2022-07-20T01:20:01.876Z",
"requestId": "DRFVQWYWJAHWZ8JR",
"extendedRequestId": "hFfxnwUjbtG/yBPYG+GW3B+XfzgNiI7KBqZ1vLLwDqs/D9Qo+YfIc9dVOxqpMo8NKDtHlw3Uglk=",
"statusCode": 403,
"retryable": false,
"retryDelay": 60.622127086356855
}
```

I have two users in my .aws/credentials file. One is the default (which is my work account). The other is called "personal". I have tried to push with

```
amplify push
amplify push --profile default
amplify push --profile personal
```

It always results in the same.

I followed the procedure located [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-assume-role-cli/) under the title "Create environment variables to assume the IAM role and verify access" and entered a new AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and a new AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY. When I then run the command ...

```
aws sts get-caller-id
```

It returns the correct Arn. However, there is a AWS_SESSION_TOKEN variable that the docs say need to be set, and I have no idea what that is.

Running amplify push under this new profile still results in an error.

I have also tried

```
AWS_PROFILE=personal aws sts get-caller-identity
```

Again, this results in the correct settings, but the amplify push still fails for the same reasons.

At this point, i'm ready to drop it and move to something else. I've been debugging this for literally months now and it would be far easier to setup a standard react app on S3 and stand up my resources manually without dealing with this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the `amplify` folder there is a `.config` directory. There are three files:

```
local-aws-info.json
local-env-info.json
project-config.json
```

`project-config.json` is required, but the `local-*` files maintain state for your local configuration. Delete these and you can reinit the project and reauthenticate the amplify cli for the environment

Answer (score 0):

This is the same issue for me. There seems to be no way to reconfigure the CLI once its authentication method is set to profile. I'm trying to change it back to amplify studio and have not been able to crack the code on updating it. Documentation in this area is awful.